# Yammer embedded application iframe

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to create an App that has an embedded page (iframe/etc) inside Yammer ?
In Yammer we can create standalone application that interact with Yammer, Can we this application inside Yammer?

Answer (score 2):

You can inject (static) OpenGraph content into Yammer, but you can't inject dynamic content through the platform, and definitely not iframes. Check out the [Yammer Developer Center Open Graph documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/open-graph) for use cases and examples.